# jquery move div slow after hide another div

Tags: jquery, performance, html, hide

I have many divs (boxes) near each other horizontally floated right, each with it's own close button. When I close one div the others move to the right to close the space of the closed div.

What I need to do if I want them to move slowly??

---

please see this example:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/2t9A6/2/`
```

when I uncheck checkbox, I want to move the other divs (the selected and not selected) SLOWLY ..

---

Please advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code you're trying. It will be hard to help you without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .animate

```
$("div").animate({left:'250px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

I'm not totally sure what you are asking.

But this might help you.